# Raising money for a charity drive

Tags: halal-haram, money, sadaqah

Salamu alaykum!

There is a charity drive being organized by fans of an (non-Muslim) artist to mark his birthday. The money will go to a fund to which he previously expressed his support, that is run by Muslims and that builds schools and promotes education in many countries (Mostly Muslim ones).

I'm a bit of a fan myself, but I'm only interested in taking part in the organization of the campaign because of the fund the proceeds will go to. The people who are donating are both Muslims and non-Muslims (and are willing to donate a lot).

I know that it is allowed to accept money from non-Muslims for charity fundraisers, but I am not sure if it's okay to do it in the context of a celebrity's birthday charity drive! Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
              In the name of Allah the most compassionate the most merciful
```

In regard to your inquiry:

> Raising money for a charity drive

Perhaps it could be permissible by paying heed to some points, among:

- If there is no sin during performing this act (charity drive…) in
  different fields
- If its profit would be for Muslims as you mentioned “that builds
  schools and promotes education in many countries…”
- If it is not considered as a Bid’ah. I mean you don’t do it as if it
  is an Islamic act. Since as we know, Bid’ah means:

> ادخال ما لیس من الدین فی الدین
>
> Namely: Attributing something to the deen or religion (Islam) which is
>   not available in the deen.

---

**Reference**:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa2363)